# Angular 2/4+ Shared Module: To forRoot() or not to forRoot()

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-services, angular-module

Ever since digging past the first few basic levels of Angular dependency injection (DI), and striking the gem that is forRoot(), I have been wondering exactly what the best practices are for actually using it.

I stumbled across the method while in search of a way to allow a lazy loaded module to access a service within the root's context, allowing a stream of data to be shared between two modules, one or both of which may be lazy loaded. Since then I have wondered, could you use forRoot() for everything in a shared module and save a lot of import statements throughout an application? What are the catches? Are there certain things that are easily used in for root, and other things that aren't? Or was for root primarily developed to bridge the aforementioned DI context issue when bridging lazy loaded modules?

Comment: What do you mean "for everything in a shared module"? How would it save import statements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The purpose of `forRoot()` is to have `singleton services` in the application.

The meaning of the `forRoot()` is to have only one instance of the `service` which was exported by that `ModuleWithProviders`. Without the `forRoot()` if you have added a `service` in the module's `providers` and use that module in many places, you can have many instances of that `service` in the different layers of your application.  With `forRoot()` , it will create a new instance of a `service`, if the last was not found anywhere.

Comment: This is the confirmation I was looking for. I had heard rumblings that it could be used to pull in more than services, but didn't really see any concrete evidence.

Answer (score 1):

The `forRoot` static method is just a convention for **configure** the module's providers.

for example: `RouterModule.forRoot`:
You pass the routes to `forRoot` method in order to configure the app-wide Router service with routes.

Create a SharedModule with the components, directives, and pipes that you use everywhere in your app.

The SharedModule should not have providers for [reasons explained here](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#why-is-it-bad-if-sharedmodule-provides-a-service-to-a-lazy-loaded-module). Nor should any of its imported or re-exported modules have providers. If you deviate from this guideline, know what you're doing and why.